# Error in "from . import views" in urls.py while making migrations

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
import createArrangement
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'file2/$', views.index2, name='index2')
]
```

I also tried writing

```
from .views import index,index2
```

with

```
url(r'^$', index,name='index')
```

Also tried writing the "from Appname" instead of "from .", but nothing worked.

Error i got is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\seatAllocatorWeb\seatAllocatorWeb\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
url(r'^createArrangement/', include('createArrangement.urls'))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 52, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\seatAllocatorWeb\createArrangement\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
from . import views
```

Comment: What is the create Arrangement that you import at the top?

Comment: It's something I tried. It has no use and the error exists even if I remove it. @KarimNGorjux

Comment: Are you importing anything from this file to any other file? If so, what?

Comment: Check your file structure: _urls.py_, _views.py_ and `__init__.py` need to be all at the same level for this to work. This should be the case if you created your app using standard Django admin commands, but maybe you changed something afterwards.

Comment: It's a circular import issue. You are messing with the imports on your files. Check the views module, the create Arrangement and the init. It's a circular import issue for sure.